# Arithmetic sequence whose any five consecutive elements contain a prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, induction, arithmetic-progressions

Consider an arithmetic sequence $\{11 + 13k : k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \}$
Does this sequence contain five consecutive composites?
If we look at some selections of five consec. elements:
$$11, 24, 37, 50, 63 \quad 50, 63, 76, 89, 102 $$
one may get the feeling that Any selection of 5 consecutive elements always contains a prime.

EDIT: non-sensical gibberish

Or is there a counter-example to this claim?

Comment: $\{102,115,128,141,154\}$. is a small counterexample.

Comment: I would guess that the opposite is true: any arithmetic progression contains a sequence of composites of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the system of congruences
$$13x\equiv -11\pmod{2}, \quad13(x+1)\equiv -11\pmod{3},\quad 13(x+2)\equiv -11\pmod{5},\quad 13(x+3)\equiv -11\pmod{7},\quad 13(x+4)\equiv -11\pmod{11}.$$
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, this has infinitely many solutions. So there are infinitely many consecutive $5$-tuples of our sequence which are respectively divisible by $2,3,5,7,11$. The idea generalizes. We can get arbitrarily long strings of composites.

Comment: proving the impossible always was problematic :D Thanks, with CRT this suddenly became so lucid.

Answer (score 3):

A well known way of generating a sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers that aren't prime is to consider $(n+1)!+2, (n+1)!+3,\ldots, (n+1)!+n$ - it's quite obvious that each of these numbers are divisible by $2, 3,\ldots, n$.

We could perform that for $n=65$, the generated sequencemust contain five consecutive elements of your sequence, thus producing a counterexample (way larger than what has already been posted in a comment, but this way you can solve a lot of similar problems).

Answer (score 2):

No, because the density of primes in this, and any other, arithmetic progression is 0.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions for details.