# Show that any arithmetic progression contains a sequence of composites of arbitrary length

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

My question is inspired by
this one:

[Arithmetic sequence whose any five consecutive elements contain a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793258/arithmetic-sequence-whose-any-five-consecutive-elements-contain-a-prime)

A more precise form:

Let
$(x_n)|_{n=1}^{\infty}$
be an arithmetic progression
such that
$x_n
=an+b
$,
where
$a$ and $b$ are integers.

Show that,
for each integer $m$,
there are $m$ consecutive composites
in the progression.

More precisely,
for each integer $m$
there is a $k(m)$
such that
$(x_{k(m)+i})_{i=1}^m$
are all composite.

I'm not sure how to prove this.

Two possibilities come to mind.

First,
somehow using the
Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Second,
generalizing the observation that
$n!+k$
for $k=2$ to $n$
are all composite.

Also,
this might also be true
where the progression is polynomial
rather than linear,
so
$x_n = p(n)$
where $p$ is a polynomial
that takes integer values at the integers.

Comment: Take $k$ distinct primes $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^k$ none of which divide the period, $P$, of the progression and simultaneously solve the $k$ congruences $A+(m+i)P\equiv 0\pmod {p_i}$ for $m$ (where $A$ is some starting term for the progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding a prime gap of length $am$ that starts above $b$ will certainly do it -- and since there are arbitrarily long prime gaps this is always possible.

(This is essentially Henrik's answer to the linked question).

Comment: Duh. I should have thought of this.